# Misguided testing

Tags: story, physics

Tom's job was to test light sensors for the Navy. He would mount 4 sensors at a time in a test circuit, then shine a light at them and measure the output.

"Sensor #157 is clearly the best," Tom concluded. "It's signal is weak, but the relative noise is 42% lower than any of the other sensors on the board. That's really amazing!"

"I can tell right away you've made a mistake," said Tom's boss.

What was Tom's mistake?

**Rules:**

- Tom's boss doesn't know any more than we do.
- 42% (not 41% or 43%) must be the key clue to the answer.
- Some knowledge of electronics is involved. But it doesn't matter how you explain the electronics so long as you can say where 42% comes from.

Comment: Does he test all four sensors on the board at once, or does he test them one at a time, in order?

Comment: @Vaekor He tests them at the same time.

Comment: He chose the other leading sensors over "tide"...

Comment: I added the physics tag to this question since it apparently requires knowledge of electrical circuits. If this isn't the case feel free to remove it.

Comment: What does "relative noise" mean, SNR inverted??

Comment: @JonathanAllan yes, SNR inverted.

Comment: I will also add that Tom's boss doesn't know any more than we do.

Comment: Owen, I see that this is in danger of getting closed as "too broad". How sure are you that your intended answer is markedly better than the others that have been posted here? (If you have something incredibly clever in mind that everyone's missed so far, this shouldn't be closed as too broad; if you're just waiting for us to guess the specific solution you have in mind, it probably should.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Thank you for the advice. I *do* think my answer is better :p, but I will edit the question to make it more restrictive.

Comment: So, apparently the 42% is essential to understanding Tom's boss's comment. So there must be some impossibility about (noise/signal for #157) = 0.58 (noise/signal for next best) together with "signal level for #157 is low", for which that figure of 0.58 (or 0.42) is critical. I confess I can't imagine how that could be given that "Tom's boss doesn't know any more than we do".

Comment: I mean, in the absence of further information it seems like the "relative noise" could take absolutely any value from zero up to substantially bigger than 1 (though the sensor would be no fun to use in the latter case). It doesn't have to be discrete because the measurement process could involve an arbitrarily large amount of averaging.

Comment: I suppose one possibility is that 42% is obviously wrong not because it's impossible but because there's a very easy way for it to appear as a result of Tom screwing up. 42% is what you get if you round 3/7 down to the next integer percentage, but that doesn't seem obviously relevant here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> the tester got one of the signal lines and the ground line transposed.

resulting in

> one signal that's the sum of the other sensors signal currents and the other sensors having the voltage noise of the sensor 157 added to them.

the fact that 0.58 is $\sqrt{1/3}$ is probably signifigant here.

Comment: I tried to comment "bingo" but apparently that's too short.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like there are a lot of possibilities depending on things that Tom's boss knows and we don't. Perhaps

> these sensors are of a known type whose signal-to-noise ratio is well understood and never varies by anything like 42%. (Or: whose sensitivity is well understood and basically never varies at all.)

Or perhaps

> these sensors are known to introduce minimal noise of their own, so that SNR is almost entirely determined by the signal level (and in particular a lower-signal sensor on the same board shouldn't be able to have better SNR).

Or perhaps

> as Quark suggests in his answer, relative noise in these sensors is always higher when the signal is lower (e.g., because it's almost entirely shot noise).

Or perhaps

> there were fewer than 157 different sensors, so Tom must have been testing the wrong thing (perhaps another, more expensive part).

Or perhaps

> the metric that actually matters for their application is sensitivity and not relative noise, so Tom's conclusion is inconsistent with his observations.

Or, for that matter, maybe

> Tom's words quoted in the question were from a *written* report and his boss was complaining about the "It's" rather than about anything to do with the sensors.

Comment: The last one - lol.

Comment: Glad you like it :-). (I actually reckoned there was maybe a 10% chance that was the intended answer. But Owen has been around here since I posted it, so I think we can assume that if it were he'd have said so by now.)

Answer (score 2):

I think that:

> Tom ran sensor #157 alone, or not as one of four. (Guessing by the number, which is one more than a number divisible by four)

Comment: It's possible that in a batch Tom had sensors 156, 157, 158, 159

Answer (score 2):

Possibly,

> The readings are reversed, and that particular sensor is more sensitive and has more noise. This conclusion would come from the fact that signal-to-noise ratio should be lower in low lighting conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Does the 42 have to do with

> the "Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy" ?

Just a thought

Answer (score 0):

the noise is not lower, but higher.

> Tom said, relative noise. so, 
>     4 sensors was tested at the same time. 
>   noise is 42% HIGER than 3 sensor, where each noise is 19%.
>     100 - 42 = 58, 
>   58 / 3 sensors = 19%

Comment: If I understand this right, you're suggesting that the only noise is common to all sensors. That fact would be a thing Tom's boss knows and we don't, contrary to what the questioner's told us...

Comment: You right @GarethMcCaughan, I need more clue. Jus wondering, 42 is a trap.